# Create class that is both a nn.Parameter and nn.Module

Tags: pytorch

To facilitate managing trainable hyperparameters, I am looking for a way to create a class `Hyperparameter` that acts both as a [nn.Parameter](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/parameter.html#Parameter) and a [nn.Module](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module). In particular, I would like to use `Hyperparameter` objects both as a nn.Parameter (e.g. for tensor operations) but still have access to the interface provided by nn.Module to for example store the objects in a nn.ModuleDict along with other modules or use methods like `zero_grad()`, `parameters()`.

I tried to accomplish this through multiple inheritance but it didn't quite work out:

```py
import torch

class Hyperparameter(torch.nn.Parameter, torch.nn.Module):
    def __new__(cls, tensor, name):
        return torch.nn.Parameter.__new__(cls, data=tensor)

    def __init__(self, tensor, name):
        torch.nn.Parameter.__init__(self)
        torch.nn.Module.__init__(self)
        self.register_parameter(name, self)

hp1 = Hyperparameter(torch.ones(5), "test1")
hp2 = Hyperparameter(torch.ones(8), "test2")

# Examples of what I want to do, which already work
tmp = hp1 * hp2
hp_dict = torch.nn.ModuleDict({"hp1": hp1, "hp2": hp2})

# What does not work with this solution
hp_dict.to(torch.device("cpu"))
# KeyError: "attribute 'data' already exists"
```

This works for the things I described (can be added to ModuleDict, can perform algebraic operations, ...), but calling `to()` throws an error. I think something is no longer as nn.Module expects it to be, but I do not understand what it is.

EDIT: Here is the full stack trace as requested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 16, in <module>
    hp_dict.to(torch.device("cpu"))
  File ".myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 612, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
  File ".myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 359, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File ".myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 384, in _apply
    param.data = param_applied
  File ".myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 796, in __setattr__
    self.register_parameter(name, value)
  File ".myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 316, in register_parameter
    raise KeyError("attribute '{}' already exists".format(name))
KeyError: "attribute 'data' already exists"
```

Comment: That looks like a very weird idea, can you detail a bit more why you need the interfaces provided by both classes ? In particular, what algebraic manipulations are you referring to which require your object to be a parameter ? The error itself probably comes from the multiple inheritance, there may be an attribute that exist in both classes. I am not an expert of python multiple inheritance though

Comment: I agree that this sounds like a weird idea without more context. So far I use a ModuleDict that stores ParameterLists to manage hyperparameters. This provides all the conveniences of nn.Module when dealing with hyperparameter gradients etc. Some hyperparameters however only have a single list entry. In these cases the Hyperparameter class I describe would be natural to have.

Comment: A full stack trace would help in tracking down the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need both, `nn.Module` and `nn.Parameter` at the same object.
You can have a `nn.Module` that is basically the parameter:

```py
class Hyperparameter(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, tensor, name):
        super(Hyperparameter, self).__init__()
        self.register_parameter(name=name, param=nn.Parameter(tensor))
        self._name = name
        
    def forward(self):
      return getattr(self, self._mame)  # expose the parameter via forward
```

Now you can have a `Hyperparameter` Module:

```py
my_hp = Hyperparameter(name='hyper', data=torch.arange(3.).requires_grad_(True))
```

Now you can access the hyper parameter `hyper` in several ways:

```py
In [1]: list(my_hp.named_parameters())
Out[1]:
[('hyper', Parameter containing:
  tensor([0., 1., 2.], requires_grad=True))]

In [2]: my_hp.hyper
Out[2]:
Parameter containing:
tensor([0., 1., 2.], requires_grad=True)

In [3]: my_hp()
Out[3]:
Parameter containing:
tensor([0., 1., 2.], requires_grad=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! That is a good suggestion. I can accomplish something similar by wrapping the hyperparameter in a ParameterList, i.e. `hp1 = torch.ParameterList([param]) `. The subtle but important distinction for me however is, that I would like to access the hyperparamter by using it as an attribute, e.g. `hp1 * 3` instead of `hp1[0] * 3`

Comment: @smonsays I'm not sure what your trying to accomplish here.